# Set-up for home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I am a beginner in networks, and I am planing to set up a network in my flat, and I am not sure how I should do that. I have optical fiber and my current speed of network is 1Gb/s Download and 300Mb/s upload. Next, an optical fiber should be connected to the switch. I am not sure if it is possible to connect the switch directly to optic fiber, skipping the internet provider modem (internet provider said It can be omitted). Then I am planing a patch panel with 3/4 wired rj45 devices and a router in which I would like to configure 4 Wi-Fi networks. The Wi-Fi networks I am planing to have been:

- **PRIVATE** → users should have the possibility to control devices connected to **IOT** network
- **WORK** → users should have the possibility to control devices connected to **IOT** network
- **GUEST** → users should NOT have the possibility to control devices connected to **IOT** network
- **IOT** → users should NOT have access to any other network. IOT network should not have access to the internet.

To create this Wi-Fi network, I am planning to use a router with OpenWrt.

I would like to also mention that all devices with wired connection should also have access to **IOT** devices.

I would like to learn:

1. Is such a configuration possible?
2. Do I miss something?
3. Hardware recommendations...

Hardware that I think can work for me:

- Router: [NETGAR Nighthawk 7800](https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/routers/r7800/)
- Switch: [NETGAR GS308T](https://www.netgear.com/business/wired/switches/smart/gs308t/) OR [NETGAR GS308E](https://www.netgear.com/business/wired/switches/plus/gs308e/)

Below you can find a simplified diagram with what I would like to achieve.
[image]

Comment: 1. surely your router would be what is connected to the fiber, not a switch. The switch would be connected to the router. 2. you can achieve what you need using openwrt, I have similar set up. 3. Use VLANs (and a smart VLAN capable switch for best performance)

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for open wrt router?

Comment: No, that would be off topic - nothing wrong with the router you considered. Note. I recommend a smart/managed switch though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is such a configuration possible?

Yes, with a few of caveats.

Caveat #1 - Some IOT devices use broadcast protocols - as such if you divide up your network you may have difficultly discovering IOT devices - a work around might be to initially connect to the IOT network to do the discovery then switch back - however I can't guarantee that will work.

Caveat #2 - On the 2.4 GHz WIFI band some people will recommend you  use a maximum of 3 WIFI networks specifically on the bands: 1, 6 and 11 due to overlapping frequency ranges (if you use more, they can interfere with each other). I don't think the 5 GHz and 6 GHz bands have the same problem.

Caveat #3 - Your description implies that the IOT devices are unable to initiate any network connections themselves (they can't access either the internet or any control hardware), are you sure they will work in this configuration? If this is the real requirement only the third (VLAN) configuration can actually provide it - if you can (or are forced to relax this requirement) the other options may be suitable.

> 2. Do I miss something?

Do you really need such a complex network, for example:

- Could you combine the IOT and Guest networks - assuming you only allow a few friends to connect to it - does it really matter if they have IP level access to the IOT devices - there is probably additional authentication required anyway.
- Can you also combine the work and private networks - frankly the two devices I usually need to access are Printers and NAS (Network attached storage) personally I want to be able to access both from "work" and "personal" computers.

> 3. Hardware recommendations...

I am not familiar enough with the plethora of hardware currently available to give a specific recommendation, however I will suggest some possible configurations.

You are probably looking at 1 of 3 network configurations:

- Router with Guest WIFI
- Double NAT.
- VLAN based.

## Router with Guest WIFI

If you can simplify your network to just two zones:

- IOT + Guest
- Work + Private

You can probably just buy a router that supports multiple WIFI networks (typically guest and private) you can put all your IOT devices on the guest network.

Your private stuff can then be either wired or connect to the private WIFI.

## Double Nat

Doesn't require any special hardware (any 2 home routers will do),
but it can only really handle two zones: Guest and Private

```
+-------------+   +----------+ ------------- +----------+ 
| Fiber Modem | - | Router 1 |               | Router 2 | --\ 
+-------------+   +----------+ --\           +-----------   |  
                                 |                          |
                              Guest +IOT              Private + Work
```

Both routers are configured with NAT, for example:

- Your guest network might be: 172.16.0.0/24
- Your private network might be 192.168.0.0/24

Some people view double NAT as a "poor" solution, but there have been times I have used it and the only real issue I had was that when port forwarding I had to configure both routers and make sure both routers have pass through support for any more complex protocols I wanted to use.

Most home routers expose a flat network - one or more WIFI channels and the wired ports, hence by connecting (either wired or wireless) to a specific router you gain access to that zone.

The double NAT will exacerbate caveat #1 - it's really unlikely you will be able to discover IOT devices across NAT and its less likely the work around will work. However if you already have two routers, you can test this for free and see if it works...

## VLAN

The "proper" solution for what you are trying to do is to use VLAN aware hardware.

```
+-------------+   +--------+   +----------------+ --- +------+
| Fiber Modem | - | Router | - | Managed Switch |     | AP 1 |
+-------------+   +--------+   +----------------+ -\  +------+
                                 |          |      |
                              Private      Work    |
                                                   |  +------+
                                                   \- | AP 2 |
                                                      +------+
```

Ports on the managed switch are either "tagged" or "untagged". The untagged ports are connected to regular hardware (computers printers etc). Tagged ports are connected to other VLAN aware hardware (The router and AP's).

The router is then responsible for handling the NAT and routing traffic between the VLAN's.

Finally depending on how many WIFI networks you need to expose (and how many each AP can handle) you will need to purchase enough AP's to support that number, so if each AP can handle two different WIFI networks you will need two AP's.

Note: Some routers come with built in managed switches, two of my old routers do (NETGEAR WNDR3700 and Buffalo WZR-HP-AG300H) after I installed OpenWRT on both. However, I don't use the VLAN support as the throughput drops dramatically - If I wanted to use VLAN's, I would purchased dedicated devices to handle it.

## TL;DR

If you want a complex network and you want max throughput you are probably going to have to pay a lot for "business grade" hardware - if you simplify your requirements, such that an off the shelf home router can handle it, you will probably end up with a much cheaper solution.

Comment: I want to do sth more complex because I always wanted to learn more about networks but I never couldn't start so now I have an argument that I have to lern to do it right. Anyway thanks a lot for your advices